# ImageView displays above the ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which consists of a ListView and an Image. 
I want to place the Image above Listview (in top left corner), but on running the app only Listview is visible and Image goes behind the Listview.
I want to show image instead of first item of the list.
 Any suggestions?

 Below is the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="100">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:focusable="true"
        />

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView

        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">

    </ListView>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if you google "android listview header", you will find hundreds of useful results. Like this: https://www.android-examples.com/add-set-header-to-listview-in-android-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:id="@+id/back_button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:focusable="true"
            />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">

        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: here is your updated xml copy this and replace with existing.It will work and dont forget to mark this post as answer :)

Comment: this is not what i'm asking Saad. i want to show image instead of the first item of the list .Can you help me now ?

Comment: oh buddy sorry for misunderstanding ... Buddy you have to search for listview headers then

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:background="@android:color/background_light"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutImagevIew"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:id="@+id/back_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:focusable="true"
                />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/frameLayoutImagevIew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ListView

                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice">

            </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: there is no need to use frame layout, but I have modified your code layout

Answer (score 0):

Try to set an elevation value in the ImageView. For example: `android:elevation="5dp"`. This should solve your problem. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **headerview** to add the image at the top like

```
listview.addHeaderView(view);// view which contains that image
```

Try this.